# Multisim Christmas Lights with 4060BT not working

Tags: multisim

Hello I'm new to using multisim and I'm trying to recreate this circuit for christmas lights. It does blink as intended but it crashes after 5 seconds or so. Can anyone help a bit please or offer any ideas? I attached a google drive and links for the multisim and the figure used. Thank you.

figure based on [Confusion over a simple 4060 LED blinker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164449/confusion-over-a-simple-4060-led-blinker)
[Edited RM]

[image]

Comment: what do you expect the circuit to do? ... you have the green line shorting  the power supply

Comment: @jsotola  "Crossing lines never connect. Connecting lines never cross". :-)  - That was a copy of a 2015 shonky markup by me of an original diagram. || "Fixed" for some values of fixed.

Comment: @hootybear - Do you have a largish capacitor on the power supply rail - say 100 uF or more or much more +12V to -12V. | The LED loads MAY be causing enough power supply variation to affect the 4060.